# Can moderators see how many newsletter subscribers there are?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, newsletter, subscription

Is there a way, perhaps in Analytics, for a site's moderators to see how many people are subscribed to that site's newsletter? If not, could there be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. The mod analytics page now has a "Newsletter Subscriptions" report, which shows numbers of confirmed subscriptions and unsubscriptions per day.

Comment: Thanks! Any chance you could also provide the current total? In this case, I'm much more interested in that than in the rate of change.

Comment: You can see the total #s of confirmed subscriptions and unsubscriptions beneath the rate-of-change charts for your selected date range. So, to get the total # of subscribers, select a date range that includes the newsletter's entire history, and subtract the # of unsubscriptions from the # of confirmed subscriptions.